# App crashes up when opening url in safari

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, safari, nsurl

I'm trying to open url in safari with this code:

```
- (IBAction)webButton:(id)sender {

    NSString *url = @"www.google.com";

    url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];


}
```

But every time app crashes up.

Has someone been in similar situation?

Here is ss off crash: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/77033905/urlInSafariCrashesUp.png

**UPDATE:**

```
NSString *recipients = @"mailto:first@example.com?subject=Hello from Croatia!";
    NSString *body = @"&body=It is sunny in Croatia!";

    NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", recipients, body];
    email = [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:email]];
```

This is for opening mail but same over sharedApplication. It crashes up to.

**UPDATE 2:**
Console log:
argv    char ** 0xbffff520
*argv   char *  0xbffff658
**argv  char    '/'
argc    int 1

**UPDATE 3:**
It calls IBAction but crashes up. When I try this code in root view it works. I addedd and connected in IB button and everything is ok with that.

Is there problem with calling UIApplication sharedApplication in subview? Should I call on different way?

**UPDATE 4:**

I figure it out that problem is even when i call empty IBAction in subview, so problem obviously is not in UIApplication but in calling IBAction in subview.

```
- (IBAction)webButton:(id)sender {

  // empty

}
```

**UPDATE 5:**
Solution: [How to call IBAction in subview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515259/how-to-call-ibaction-in-subview/10516023#10516023)

Comment: tryed on iphone. Crashes up to.

Comment: are you sure your IBAction is wired up correctly? Can you place a break point in the webButton method to make sure you are getting into that method?

Comment: yes, i'm getting in method. Pls take a lok at UPDATED first post.

Comment: Can you please post the consol ouput of the crash?

Comment: this I found in one post (stack): "It may be possible that you need to retain the URL object. That was once the issue for me". Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775077/uiapplications-openurl-crashes-my-app

Comment: @Joe - updated again first post

Comment: View -> Debug Area -> Activate Console

Comment: @Joe - sorry, I updated first post and added console log.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11032/discussion-between-croios-and-joe)

Comment: I cannot work blocks that. :-/

Comment: Solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515259/how-to-call-ibaction-in-subview/10516023#10516023

Answer (score 3):

You are not providing a valid URL, an URL is always of the form `scheme:<host part>`.

```
// This is correct and will work:
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]

// Updated with body and subject:
NSMutableString* url = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"mailto:"];
[url appendString:@"first@example.com"];
[url appendFormat:@"?subject=%@", [@"Hello from Croatia" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[url appendFormat:@"&body=%@", [@"This is a body" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

Comment: I think you have something else going wrong, I use this same code all the time and theres nothing wrong with it.

Comment: It crashes up again with you code to. I'm calling above code in my subview, maybe is this the problem. Because when I try to call this code in root view it work's.

Comment: @CroiOS You need to make it more clear what you are trying to accomplish, and exactly what is going wrong. Your updates keep changing your question.

Comment: Yes, my updates changing question because i tought that problem was in UIApplication but it's not. And on that i open new question because it's not same like this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515259/how-to-call-ibaction-in-subview

Answer (score 1):

Does it crash if you do something like

```
NSString *url = @"http://www.google.com";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

I believe you need the "**http://**" in there.

Comment: This is not strange at all, if you percent escape `http://www.google.com` you will get: `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com` which is not a valid URL (see my answer below).

Comment: The solution is @SveinungKvalBakken's method.

Comment: but it's not working to me, I made update on first post. pls take a look

Comment: Did you read my post?
You're escaping away the special characters used to separate the scheme, host and parameters, see how you should escape only the contents of the URL parameters, not the URL itself.

Comment: which part of my url should I escape?