# How to call IBAction in subview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ibaction

When I try to call IBAction in root view it works, but when I call in subView app creashes.

Code:

```
- (IBAction)webButton:(id)sender {

  NSLog(@"doesn't print log");

}
```

Here is ss off crash: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/77033905/urlInSafariCrashesUp.png

Thank's for help

UPDATE: 
Example code: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/77033905/IBActionSubView.zip

Comment: what error u see in log file?

Comment: That isn't enough information to fix the problem.  You can, of course, call an method within a subview so the issue lies elsewhere in your code and you will have to reveal some of it to us.

Comment: Are you using ARC in your project?

Comment: Use Xcode's breakpoint navigator to set a break on unhandled Objective-C exceptions.  That should give better information about what's generating the error.  The line that's flagged in that capture is just a dumb Xcode default, not the real problem.

Comment: I bet he is trying to get the action from a deallocated instance of the view Controller and that's why it's crashing...

Comment: I have no more informations. I've put over IB in subView nib file button like I always do in root view and call IBAction like I always do but when I call in subView app get crashed.

Comment: @Lefteris - How can I check if I'm using? Sry, I'm noob.

Comment: Well the simplest way is to write this line in your code: NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];
if you get a warning, you are using ARC :-)

Comment: I updated post. Pls take a look at my example code. Thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create your SubViewController, the variable `sub` that points to it is local to the `addSubViewButton:` method and will be released when that method ends.  You need to keep a strong reference to that controller so that it's not deallocated before you use it.

Comment: Can you tell me pls how can I do that?

Comment: In ViewController.h, create a property: `@property (strong, nonatomic) SubViewController *sub;`.  Then, instead of having a local variable called `sub`, assign the object to the property.  (If this is going to be used in a real program, you also have the problem of what to do if someone taps "Add subview" twice.)

Comment: It works, thank you very much for help. In real project it's not gonna be exactly like here.

Comment: This Phillip's answer really helped me who has been digging into the similar problem. I set a custom view for showing popup, then got it taken as subview from a super view(with alloc and init), but the iBAction connected to a UIButton on the subview never responded. The cause was 'reference'. I had been creating the subview with local variable, and once I set it with property with strong, it suddenly started to work as I imagined. Thx.